# SSRS not letting me change dataset of a table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report with a table in it. I need to change the dataset that this table uses. When I go the tablix properties and try to change the DataSetName, it automatically gets reverted back to the original dataset instead of the new one I selected.

Any ideas on how to fix it and why it's happening?

Comment: That is a really weird problem. Have you checked that the dataset is shown in the Report Data (View -> Report Data). Also, are your bindingSources correctly connected?

Comment: Does the new dataset name contain any illegal characters?

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out that whoever designed the report, had the entire report inside a table with one gigantic column, that column had a rectangle which contained the entire report. So obviously my table kept inheriting the datasource from the root table. I took out the needless table and rectangle, and the report now works as desired. Thanks guys for trying to help, much appreciated :)

Comment: @Mogambo, you should post the comment as an answer. definitely helped the SSRS newbie here!

Comment: @Illuminati done! I'm glad it helped you out.

Comment: cool, here is 15 pts! ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out that the entire report was inside a table with one gigantic column. That column had a rectangle which contained the entire report. So obviously my table kept inheriting the datasource from the root table. I took out the needless "root" table and rectangle, and the report now works as desired. Thanks guys for trying to help, much appreciated :)

Comment: Came here looking for some answers and this one worked straight away. Crazy how we tend to overlook small things.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your tables(or matrix) inside one `List` as I did, this will also not allow you to set different datasets to each table.

Removing the List worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same kind of issue, but i was able to overcome by below mentioned way.

I've created a sub report and placed rectangle inside the sub report with page break option checked before and placed all my sub report content inside the rectangle. This page break works only if the sub report renders any data if not they will be no page break.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit with Notepad++ or something similar you can see that it is just an XML. You can alter the DataSet from the text editor and reopen.